# Praw Python doesn`t show every submission from a subreddit

Tags: python, statistics, reddit, praw

```
 def get_submissions(self):
        for submission in self.reddit.subreddit("all").new(limit=None):
            self.submissions.append(submission.title)
        print(self.submissions,len(self.submissions))
```

This is my code. I am trying to get all submissions from a subreddit, but somehow, it stops at a certain value. I am trying to build a statistic over a subreddit, and I kinda need to fetch a big amount of posts, more than 2000, maybe. But this method gives me everytime <870 posts.

Do you guys know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reddit API has a limit of about 1000 items per listing, so you won't be able to get more than that with PRAW. To get more posts, one option is PushShift.io, a third-party service that has more data on Reddit items. PushShift has an API wrapper called PSAW.

Comment: so there is absolutely no chance to get more posts from a listing using the reddit api?

Comment: Exactly. The cap is ~1000. As I say in my answer, you can get more Reddit posts from third party sources (PushShift).